# How can I get the current PHP executable from within a script?

Tags: php

I want to run a PHP CLI program from within the PHP CLI. On some machines where this will run, both PHP 4 and PHP 5 are installed. If I run the outer program as

```
php5 outer.php
```

I want the inner script to be run with the same PHP version. In Perl, I would use `$^X` to get the Perl executable. It appears there isn't any such variable in PHP.

Right now, I'm using `$_SERVER['_']`, because Bash (and zsh) sets the environment variable `$_` to the last-run program. But, I'd rather not rely on a shell-specific idiom.

*UPDATE:* Version differences are but one problem. If PHP isn't in [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), for example, or isn't the first version found in PATH, the suggestions to find the version information won't help.

Additionally, `csh` and variants appear to not set the `$_` environment variable for their processes, so the workaround isn't applicable there.

*UPDATE 2:* I was using `$_SERVER['_']`, until I discovered that it doesn't do the right thing under `xargs` (which makes sense... `zsh` sets it to the command it ran, which is `xargs`, not `php5`, and `xargs` doesn't change the variable). I am falling back to using:

```
$version = explode('.', phpversion());
$phpcli = "php{$version[0]}";
```

Comment: Is it possible to simply conditionally include the other PHP file?  That's the easiest way to insure the included code runs with the same interpreter as the including code.

Comment: Interesting point.  In this particular case, part of the reason it's being run as a subprocess is that the inner script calls 'exit()' at various places.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is worth noting that now in PHP 5.4+ you can use the predefined constant [PHP_BINARY](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php):

> PHP_BINARY
>
> Specifies the PHP binary path during script execution. Available since PHP 5.4.

Comment: Note: in Apache2handler return `httpd` path.

Comment: note: it returns the `php-cgi` and not `php` in my case (windows)

Comment: This returns `C:\php` on Windows where no such file or directory exists (PHP 7.1.11, Apache 2.4.29, Windows 7 Pro) - as, as noted in a comment on another answer, does `PHP_BINDIR`.

Comment: And on the hosting company's Linux box it also returns the same as `PHP_BINDIR`.  Here it is `/usr/bin` and does contain a `php` executable, but that is the version 5.3 executable not the 7.0.25 version of the calling environment.  So I don't think this answer is useful.

Comment: @Jake How are you testing that?

Comment: @KristopherIves Via HTTP and Apache.  I must have actually been using `PHP_BINDIR` rather than `PHP_BINARY` when testing before (hence why the same values).  With `PHP_BINARY` I get:
Windows 7 32-bit / PHP 7.1.11 - `httpd.exe`;
Hosting Co. 1 (Linux / PHP 7.0.25) - `""` (empty string);
Hosting Co. 2 (Linux / PHP 7.1.7) - `.../php-cgi` (correct path for version).
So on only one of 3 systems is it giving the correct value.

Comment: For php-fpm (on Debian) this returns `/usr/sbin/php-frpm7.3` which cannot be used to launch any PHP script. While technically correct, it's completely useless for OP's purpose.

Answer (score 9):

On my server I've PHP 5.3.14.

I've found a predefined constant: [`PHP_BIN_DIR`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-bindir)

Then, supposing the file name of the executable file is always 'php', `$php_cmd = PHP_BIN_DIR.'/php'` points to my PHP executable file.

Comment: [According to the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php), which doesn't say when it was added, it's `PHP_BINDIR` (no second underscore).  This is a pretty decent answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I upvoted the answer and the comment but took the upvotes back after trying it in Windows. Will always return `C:\php` no matter the reality.

Comment: Nice answer, however, it won't work as expected if multiple versions of PHP are installed on a Linux system, since they will likely all be in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 6):

**Update;** nowadays `PHP_BINARY` works with `XAMPP` as well (Tested with XAMPP that comes with PHP 7.4).

---

### Old Answer

Unfortunately PHP_BINARY is returning the `httpd` binary (on Windows [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP)), so I'm back to using paths...

```
    if (defined('PHP_BINARY') &&
                PHP_BINARY &&
                in_array(PHP_SAPI, array('cli', 'cli-server')) &&
                is_file(PHP_BINARY)) {

          return PHP_BINARY;
    } else if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
        $paths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, getenv('PATH'));
        foreach ($paths as $path) {
            if (substr($path, strlen($path)-1) == DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) {
                $path = substr($path, 0, strlen($path)-1);
            }
            if (substr($path, strlen($path) - strlen('php')) == 'php') {
                $response = $path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'php.exe';
                if (is_file($response)) {
                    return $response;
                }
            } else if (substr($path, strlen($path) - strlen('php.exe')) == 'php.exe') {
                if (is_file($response)) {
                    return $response;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $paths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, getenv('PATH'));
        foreach ($paths as $path) {
            if (substr($path, strlen($path)-1) == DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) {
                $path = substr($path, strlen($path)-1);
            }
            if (substr($path, strlen($path) - strlen('php')) == 'php') {
                if (is_file($path)) {
                    return $path;
                }
                $response = $path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'php';
                if (is_file($response)) {
                    return $response;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
```

Comment: Has someone tried it? Does it work? Consistently and across Win and Unix? The code is ugly, but if it works, I'll normalize it.

Comment: I know this is an old answer an no one has answers @XedinUnknown but I can confirm this works perfectly on Windows running XAMPP. Has anyone else tested this in more environments?

Comment: +1 Very good attempt. `PHP_BINARY` does seem to work and give me `php-cgi.exe` in most cases. But in one odd setup I have, it still gives me `httpd`, even though I do have XAMPP/PHP 7.4. I also don't have php configured in my `PATH`, so the Old Answer doesn't work either. (I'm really not sure what's different in my one setup that `PHP_BINARY` doesn't work...)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so this is ugly, but it works on Linux:

```
<?php
    // Returns the full path of the current PHP executable
    function get_proc_name(){
       // Gets the PID of the current executable
       $pid = posix_getpid();

       // Returns the exact path to the PHP executable.
       $exe = exec("readlink -f /proc/$pid/exe");
       return $exe;
    }
```

It doesn't look like there's any easy way to do this for Windows. Some Windows executables like `tasklist` can give you the name of the executable, but not the full path to where the executable is. I was only able to find examples for finding the full path given a PID for [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/11104/), [AutoHotkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) and the like. If anyone has any suggestions on where else I could look, let me know.

PS: To get the [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) in PHP for Windows, you apparently have to call [getmypid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php).

Comment: I was looking into doing this too. I thought I might be able to use the [w32api](http://pecl.php.net/package/w32api) or [ffi](http://pecl.php.net/package/ffi) PECL extensions to call the [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function, but neither extension seems to be actively maintained at the moment.

Comment: Instead of faffing with `$pid` you can always just look at `"/proc/self/exe"`

Comment: I love this solution btw !

Comment: I'm using Windows, and even though you don't offer a Windows solution, the PID from `getmypid()` was for the `httpd` process... :-/

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`phpversion()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php) to get the current version of PHP before you execute the "inner" script.

Answer (score 0):

After being dissatisfied with the answers, I came up with my own.  It tries to use `PHP_BINARY` if it looks reasonable, otherwise it looks for an interpreter with the same version as the currently running one.

```
/**
 * Return a suitable PHP interpreter that is likely to be the same version as the
 * currently running interpreter.  This is similar to using the PHP_BINARY constant, but
 * it will also work from within mod_php or PHP-FPM, in which case PHP_BINARY will return
 * unusable interpreters.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPhpInterpreter(): string {
    static $cachedExecutable = null;

    if ($cachedExecutable !== null) {
        return $cachedExecutable;
    }

    $basename = basename(PHP_BINARY);

    // If the binary is 'php', 'php7', 'php7.3' etc, then assume it's a usable interpreter
    if ($basename === 'php' || preg_match('/^php\d+(?:\.\d+)*$/', $basename)) {
        return PHP_BINARY;
    }

    // Otherwise, we might be running as mod_php, php-fpm, etc, where PHP_BINARY is not a
    // usable PHP interpreter.  Try to find one with the same version as the current one.

    $candidates = [
        'php' . PHP_MAJOR_VERSION . '.' . PHP_MINOR_VERSION . '.' . PHP_RELEASE_VERSION,
        'php' . PHP_MAJOR_VERSION . '.' . PHP_MINOR_VERSION,
        'php' . PHP_MAJOR_VERSION,
    ];

    $envPath = $_SERVER['PATH'] ?? '';
    $paths = $envPath !== '' ? explode(':', $envPath) : [];

    if (!in_array(PHP_BINDIR, $paths, true)) {
        $paths[] = PHP_BINDIR;
    }

    foreach ($candidates as $candidate) {
        foreach ($paths as $path) {
            $executable = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $candidate;
            if (is_executable($executable)) {
                $cachedExecutable = $executable;
                return $executable;
            }
        }
    }

    // Fallback, if nothing else can be found
    $cachedExecutable = 'php';
    return $cachedExecutable;
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.  I tested it on Debian Buster, from CLI and from FPM.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately I can't find a shorter way, but *[findPHP()](https://gist.github.com/cjsewell/39b60065ae2af677ceb1)* works pretty well and is multi OS/PHP version compatible.

$lookIn could probably be extended to include more common locations.

Comment: The problem with external links is they can break at any time.

Answer (score -2):

You can try and parse the [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) result.

Comment: For clarification, you were probably downvoted (not by me) because the path to the php executable doesn't appear in `phpinfo()` (which does seem illogical to me).

Answer (score -3):

I think the best constant is [PHP_BINARY](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php). With PHP 5.5.12.

Comment: Looks identical to the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372624/get-current-php-executable-from-within-script/9182368#9182368).