# How can I get the path of the PHP binary from PHP?

Tags: php, path, bin

How can I get the binary path of `php` from PHP?

I saw it in [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php), but I need another method that gets it in Linux and Windows systems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current PHP executable from within script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372624/get-current-php-executable-from-within-script)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use:

```
$_SERVER['_']
```

Also, [the predefined constant `PHP_BINDIR`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-bindir) gives the directory where the PHP executable is found.

Sample on [CodePad](http://codepad.org/SYXHz5zP) and [Ideone](http://www.ideone.com/izdaY).

It looks like, for security reasons, `$_SERVER` values are not exposed.

Comment: In Windows, the PHP_BINDIR constant seems to point to "C:\php5" even if php is in a totally different directory, like for me "C:\dev\php". Here, PHP is setup as an apache module.

Comment: The server I was on unfortunately returned NULL, I assume due to security reasons.

Comment: PHP_BINDIR worked for me on Debian. $_SERVER['_'] didn't.

Comment: it's not working. use this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/43015868/2574125

Comment: PHP_BINDIR is set at compile time which means that it is wrong in most cases. PHP_BINARY is set at runtime. So use this instead.

Comment: PHP_BINARY (since php v5.4; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182368/3102305)

Answer (score 18):

#### Linux Only

Use the "which" command to find `php`.

```
$phpPath = exec("which php");
```

Note this does not guarantee the same `php` executable that your web server may be using, but rather the first instance that was found while looking through the paths.

Comment: Good point but most hosting services don't allow `exec` at all.

Comment: Yes, some hosts do not, others do, I guess it depends your context.

Comment: This does not necessarily result in the correct php binary, since Apache and the command line might very well be using different ones.

Answer (score 11):

A method using environment variables, assuming the `php` executable is in the system path.

```
function getPHPExecutableFromPath() {
  $paths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, getenv('PATH'));
  foreach ($paths as $path) {
    // We need this for XAMPP (Windows)
    if (strstr($path, 'php.exe') && isset($_SERVER["WINDIR"]) && file_exists($path) && is_file($path)) {
        return $path;
    }
    else {
        $php_executable = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "php" . (isset($_SERVER["WINDIR"]) ? ".exe" : "");
        if (file_exists($php_executable) && is_file($php_executable)) {
           return $php_executable;
        }
    }
  }
  return FALSE; // Not found
}
```

Comment: @ggirtsou I don't get your edit... why would the Windows Path contain an entry with "php.exe" ? If it is something specific to XAMPP please at least add a meaningful comment in the code.

Comment: @ggirtsou then add a meaningful comment in the code, because it is certainly not standard behaviour

Comment: Those file_exists() are redundant

Answer (score 9):

Maybe the best solution is in the [Symfony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) process component:

*[PhpExecutableFinder.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Process/PhpExecutableFinder.php)* and *[ExecutableFinder.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Process/ExecutableFinder.php)*. In use:

```
<?php
    use Symfony\Component\Process\PhpExecutableFinder;

    $phpFinder = new PhpExecutableFinder;
    if (!$phpPath = $phpFinder->find()) {
        throw new \Exception('The php executable could not be found, add it to your PATH environment variable and try again');
    }

    return $phpPath;
```

Answer (score 4):

Normally, in a simple default PHP installation under Windows, the *php.ini* file is located and loaded from the same directory of the PHP binary.

To simplify, Windows users:

```
echo dirname(php_ini_loaded_file()).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'php.exe';
```

Voilà!

Of course, if you are using multiple *.ini* files, it may not work if the files are not into the same PHP binary directory. BTW, this may solve to most of cases. Windows developers running PHP from local development environment.

Comment: sorry forgot to say I am using mac

Comment: Are the last two sentences (directly) connected?

Comment: This solved it for me, thanks! But you might want to add `chr(34)` so it will be `$runCommand = chr(34) . dirname(php_ini_loaded_file()).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'php.exe' . chr(34);`  in order to support spaces in the path. Needed for example if like to run it in the background like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73118719/4829915.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, using [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants), you can use the *ini* variable - *extension_dir* - as it is placed in the PHP folder.

Like this:

```
echo str_replace('ext/', 'php.exe', ini_get('extension_dir'));
```

Comment: You shouldn't correlate this logic to that setting - even in WAMP or whatever - the setting might be changed intentionally.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. This would not work inside any framework or such that need to be able to work in every project out there. This was just the solution that worked best for me at the time for my local and server setup.

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP 5.4 you can simply use the [`PHP_BINARY`](https://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-binary) reserved constant.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy!

```
var_dump(getenv('PHPBIN'));
```

But it works only on Windows, so we should use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889486/how-can-i-get-the-path-of-the-php-binary-from-php/3889630#3889630).

How did I get this? I just typed echo `echo phpinfo();` and searched the `php` path there. Just see here:

[image: How I found the PHP path]

Then I just getting it here: [php getenv](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getenv.php) and ... you see the result.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows and [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP):

```
$php = getenv('PHPRC') . '/php.exe';

if(is_file($expected)){
   return $php;
}
```