# PHP_BINDIR on Windows incorrect?

Tags: php

When I run a script on Windows using PHP 5.6 (coming from [WampServer 2.4](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)) I get this confusing result:

```
$binary = PHP_BINARY;  // $binary: "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.15\php.exe"
$bindir = PHP_BINDIR;  // $bindir: "C:\php"
```

`PHP_BINARY` is correct but `PHP_BINDIR` is completely wrong. Is the latter variable deprecated or something? Any other ideas why it would output some random path that doesn't even exist on my disk?

Comment: Could you share the script ?

Comment: This is the script. I declare two variables and run it as a unit test from PhpStorm. (The variable contents that is displayed to the right is a debugging feature of PhpStorm.)

Comment: I hope [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889486/how-to-get-the-path-of-the-php-bin-from-php) will be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PHP_BINARY` is a value set on **runtime** (when the script is executed)

`PHP_BINDIR` is a value set on **compile time**, not on runtime.

The path is set to the prefix used in configure (Linux equivalent: `./configure --prefix <path>`). The default path on windows is `C:\php`. You cannot change it without recompiling PHP.

To get the path, you should trail down `PHP_BINARY`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `PHP_BINDIR` which according to the `php-internals/11c783wgty/bug-54514` is set at compile time. This suggests this may change at some later date.

Anything set at compile time is going to be irrelevant to, at least us windows users, as we normally rely on someone else to do the compilation as Windows does not come with a free compiler. As far as I can tell this would apply to php compiled on a unix machine as well as a windows machine as there is no reason to be positive PHP is running from where it was compile into.

So dont use `PHP_BINDIR` to find where the current executable is running from.