# Artisan won't connect to mysql - Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I cloned a project which is built on laravel 4.2. Currently my Xampp has a  version 7.0.13.1 and  has php version of 7.1.

When i type `php artisan migrate`, it gives an error `[PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` which means my artisan is not connected to my mysql running on the Xampp.

In the terminal, i tried `which php` and i get `/usr/local/php5/bin/php` 
.

Could this be the cause of my problem? That the path doesn't point to my Xampp version 7.0.13.1?

PS: After cloning, i followed the steps on the github page

```
composer install

$ php artisan migrate

$ php artisan db:seed

$ php artisan serve
```

Please help?

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @Phil, i am able to migrate using `php artisan migrate --env=production` but i can't run the application. When i run the command `php artisan serve` and reload the browser, i get [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Comment: What you did after getting clone also share all steps ?

Comment: @C2486, i don't get your statement. But you mean my steps after cloning? check my update

Comment: Are you using the Xamp's MySQL socket? To do so you should use the Xamp's version of PHP, not the one you've installed globally on your system.

Comment: @AnthonyB, okay i will have to include the socket into the mysql configuration in the database.php file but how do i get the socket ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools like [XAMP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html), [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) or [WAMP](https://www.wampserver.com/en/) have their own PHP and MySQL binaries and do not use a potential globally installed version.
I guess you are using MySQL installed with XAMP, so the socket is not the
default one that you could search in your system but the one in XAMP.

You have two options:

1. Update your global PHP's `php.ini` to set the `pdo_mysql.default_socket`
   or `mysqli.default_socket` to the MySQL socket in your XAMP installation
   in order to your global PHP binary will be able to connect the your XAMP's
   MySQL version.
2. Use the XAMP's PHP binary (**recommanded**).

The recommanded option is the second one, because the XAMP's PHP binary is
already configured to use the right MySQL socket and does not need to
update any configuration file.

I explain below how to find the MySQL socket and how to locate the PHP binary directory.

**Find the MySQL socket path:**

- Write the following code in you Web server directory (usually `www/`, `htdocs/` or `public_html/`)

  ```
  <?php
  //phpinfo.php
  phpinfo();
  ```
- Open the URL `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` in your Web browser (adapt the
  host name if required).
- According to the PHP extension you use to connect to the datase search for
  either `pdo_mysql.default_socket` or `mysqli.default_socket` and you'll
  find the path to the socket file.

See [phpinfo()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

**Find the PHP binary directory:**

- Write the following code in your Web server directory

  ```
  <?php
  //bindir.php
  echo PHP_BINDIR;
  ```
- Open the URL `http://localhost/bindir.php` in your Web browser.
- The path to the directory hosting the PHP binary is written.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3889557/4932315) for the information.
See the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-bindir) about pre-defined constants.

In your case the directory hosting PHP is `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/` so you
should run the command:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php artisan migrate
```

Comment: I cant this `/opt/lampp/bin/php` in my Xampp folder

Comment: What OS are you using? On OpenSuse I just installed Xamp and the path to PHP is correct.

Comment: using OSX. specifically macOsSeria version. But  when i go the Xampp file, i dont see opt

Comment: @XamarinDevil Try `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php` on OSX? Otherwise, on your webserver use `phpinfo()`, it will say the PHP path.

Comment: yess. now i find with this `Applications/XAMPP/bin/php`

Comment: Checking my php.ini `pdo_mysql.default_socket` is empty meaning its using the default built in mysql

Comment: When executing `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php artisan migrate`, what does it say?

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166164/discussion-between-anthonyb-and-xamarindevil).

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a .env file with an existant database and an authorised user and password for that database?