# Get the path to php binary file

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run this console command from web: `shell_exec('php cli_script.php')` and it works for me on the local machine but I don't know where is php on others machines.

Is it possible to get current location of php binary for either systems Windows and Linux?
`whereis` and `which` don't work on Windows so I can't parse the output.

Comment: just set the path on the other machine to include the php interpreter

Comment: ``cd \`` then `dir php.exe /s /a /p`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current PHP executable from within script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372624/get-current-php-executable-from-within-script)