# PHP exec("which php" ) returns wrong result

Tags: php, macos

a local development site on my OS X Mavericks uses an exec("which php")-command. The result of this exec()-Command is "/usr/bin/php", which is actually wrong, it should return "opt/local/php5/bin/php".
"opt/local/php5/bin/php" is the result of the command "which php" in my Terminal-Session. How can i fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current PHP executable from within script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372624/get-current-php-executable-from-within-script)

Comment: Which "php" is used by your apache ?

Answer (score 1):

If you ask the wrong question, you get the wrong result. ;)

The `which` command returns you the full path to an executable file. Those locations where `which` looks for the command, are defined in the `$PATH` environment variable, and it looks something like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/android-sdk/sdk/platform-tools:/opt/android-sdk/sdk/tools
```

These are common command paths, separated by colons.

Apparently you have multiple installations of PHP on your machine. What you get, is the path to the primary one, probably installed by your packet manager.

The one in `/opt` will only be found if you add `/opt/local/php5/bin` to the envinonment of your webserver user, and it has to be before `/usr/bin`.

Now, how do you set the `$PATH` of your webserver? Depending on your server (Apache, Nginx, …) and your distro, there are different possibilities. For Apache on a Debian-like system, it's usually `/etc/apache2/envvars`.

If there's no `PATH` defined yet, simply add the following line:

```
export PATH="/opt/local/php5/bin:$PATH"
```

(Note that the `PATH` at the beginning doesn't have a `$` sign.)

Then restart your webserver.